# WooCommerce - Show Variation Price on Product Page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I was wondering if there was a way to show the variation price on the product page as different variations are selected. I’m unsure if there is a hook for this or not, but when I originally took over the site I manage, this was implemented. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That happens by default. I'd try switching to Twenty Sixteen to see what I mean.

Comment: I see this.  Any idea why it isn't showing up on my theme?

Comment: Best guess is that you have unnecessary and/or out of date template overrides. You can try updating your templates with newer code, or I prefer to use templates only where really necessary. You could also be hiding it with CSS. There's no way for us to know.